# Nested Replace in oracle select query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a requirement of replacing certain id values with their actual values while returning the column value. And the column is having multiple id's concatenated with comma.

Current approach I am planning to do is as below using nested replace:

```
select
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE('1,2,3','1','One'),'2','Two'),'3','Three') as content_types,
    packid,
    packsender
from packages;
```

I have total 6 such key value pairs so I would need 6 nested replace functions. Please suggest if this is the right way of doing it or not and is there any other better way.

Note: I tried to normalize the table but there are so many other factors which are preventing this so I have to derive this solution with out normalizing.

Edit: Quick Clarification: I have used 1,2,3 as reference but the keys are 5 character alphanumeric unique combinations so there wont be any scenario of partial replacement.

Sample column data I have: ***CT002,CT004,CT006***

OutPut I am expecting: ***ContentType2, ContentType4, ContentType6***

Thanks,
Vinay.

Comment: Even this approach becomes problematical, if, for example, you also need to replace the number `11`, and then you'd have to worry about which `1` is the real single digit `1`.  Really, the best solution to this is to _not_ store unnormalized CSV data in your Oracle tables.

Comment: Your approach will not work if the input may look like `'1,2,43'` - you will get `'One,Two,4Three'` - is that what you want?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, all keys are unique values the confusion of 11 an 43 will not be there in the key values set I have.

Comment: Your approach is just fine for those 5 replacements.

Comment: Fix your data structure!  Don't store ids in delimited strings!  SQL has a great data structure for storing lists.  It is called a *table* not a *string*.

Comment: "Sample" is not enough in this case. For the EXACT examples you gave, you could use a regular expression, but that will fail if other values don't follow the same pattern. I will show the regexp approach in an Answer, in a few minutes, but it may still not work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to solve the problem, after the clarification added to the original post.

Assumptions: the input string is a comma-separated list of tokens (no extraneous spaces, tabs etc.); some of the tokens may be equal to **CT002**, **CT004** or **CT006**, and these tokens must be replaced with **ContentType2**, **ContentType4** and **ContentType6**, respectively, while leaving everything else unchanged.

This can be done with a single regular expression. This solution is easier to maintain; but it may still be slower than repeated (nested) calls to REPLACE. If speed becomes an issue, both approaches should be tested on the actual data, to see which performs better.

In the sample data I created for testing (in the `WITH` clause, which is not part of the SQL query - use your actual table and column names), notice in particular the last row - to see what happens if tokens may contain CT002 (for example) as a *substring*. Also, the second row shows the token **CT002** surrounded by spaces, not immediately surrounded by commas; in this case, it will not be replaced. I give these examples to demonstrate how important it is that the format of the data be specified with 100% precision and accuracy.

The regexp is pretty basic; you may not be familiar with **subexpressions** in a regular expression, and the way they can be referenced in the third argument of `regexp_replace()` - see the documentation for that (or do a search for "subexpression in regular expression" for the more general concept, regardless of Oracle).

```
with
  sample_data (str) as (
    select 'ABC3,CT001,CT006,WHYNOT'       from dual union all
    select 'CT002,CT004,  CT006  , CT93'   from dual union all
    select 'CT002,CT002,CT004,CT002,CT006' from dual union all
    select 'ABCT002'                       from dual
  )
select str,
       regexp_replace(str, 'CT00(2|4|6)(,|$)', 'ContentType\1\2') as new_str
from   sample_data
;

STR                           NEW_STR                                                         
----------------------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------
ABC3,CT001,CT006,WHYNOT       ABC3,CT001,ContentType6,WHYNOT                                  
CT002,CT004,  CT006  , CT93   ContentType2,ContentType4,  CT006  , CT93                       
CT002,CT002,CT004,CT002,CT006 ContentType2,ContentType2,ContentType4,ContentType2,ContentType6
ABCT002                       ABContentType2
```